# Add code based validation to InfoPath forms for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, infopath, validation

I have a list where I use Infopath Forms. Users use these forms to enter data. They should also attach something in the form, but if they don't attach anything and click save, I want that the item is not saved, but a textbox becomes visible where they have to write the reason for not attaching a file. I have not found a way to accomplish this out of the box in InfoPath or SharePoint Designer 2013. I also have not found a way to enter client side code with JavaScript in InfoPath. I also don't have the possiblity to add a Content Editor web part.
Is there a way to implement this validation logic in InfoPath?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you just need to make your attachments mandatory, right!

So in this case, you can do the following:

- In your `data source`, Right-click the `attachment` field, and select `Properties`
- At `Validation`, set

  ```
  Attach is blank
  ```

> Read more at [how to make attachments mandatory in InfoPath](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/31e7993f-7085-4bfe-aa97-ed04163bb2f1/how-to-make-attachment-as-mandatory-in-infopath-when-it-is-in-repeating-section?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy),. Also, you can find another workaround at [Make attachment field mandatory in InfoPath](https://www.spguides.com/make-attachment-mandatory-infopath-sharepoint/)

Comment: No. It is not just making the attachment mandatory, but to make another control (a textbox) visible, prevent the form from closing and force to the user to enter a text, if the attachment field is blank when the user tries to save the form.